# How to check for Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0 installation in WiX

Tags: crystal-reports, wix, installation, report

I am creating a WiX Installer and need to check if a specific version of Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0 (v. 13.0.3) is installed.

I have found two ways that both seem to work (on my W7 machine), but am not sure if one or the other has any downfalls such as working on XP etc.

Option 1 (My concern with this option is if a later version is installed with a different product code, this condition will not pass):

```
<Property Id="CRVSINSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="CRVSInstalledSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AAD476D7-FC64-40BC-85EA-0C1FD98D8375}" Name="InstallDate" Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Condition Message="You don't have Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 (v. 13.0.3)  installed.">
  <![CDATA[CRVSINSTALLED]]>
</Condition>
```

Option 2:

```
<Property Id="CRVSINSTALLED2">
  <RegistrySearch Id="CRVSInstalledSearch2" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports" Name="CRRuntime32Version" Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Condition Message="You don't have Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 (v. 13.0.3)  installed 2.">
  <![CDATA[CRVSINSTALLED2 >= "13.0.3"]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: If you do decide to use the registry check above, be sure to consider that the 64Bit version of Crystal Reports might be in play. Under the same key you will find a string value for `CRRuntime64Version`.

It would appear that even the native VS2010 bootstrapper checks the registry key. Refer to the contents of the `Product.xml` file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like option2 because I personally don't like depending on registry keys in *HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*. A 3rd option is to [check the version number of a file during installation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_the_version_number.htm).

Comment: Thanks Bryan, do you have any insight on the pros/cons between 2 and 3?

Comment: I'd favor option 2 because users are more likely to be able to influence where files get installed and that may introduce some complexity in determining which file needs its version checked. The location of the registry key is easier to determine.